# How to insert imagename where id=? ... in mySQL [PHP]

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to upload avatar images to MySQL database. My code is working correctly, but the problem is with the SQL query...

This is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_FILES['avatar'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['avatar']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['avatar']['type'];

//print_r($_FILES['avatar']['name']); 

  $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['avatar']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


      //$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['avatar']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpg","gif","jpeg","png","bmp");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPG, GIF, BMP or PNG formats...";
      }

      if($file_size > 8000000){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 8 MB';
      }
//print_r($file_tmp); exit;
      if(empty($errors)==true){
          $randname = (rand(0,1000));
          $file_data=date("d-m-Y-H-i-s");
          $file_name=$file_data.$randname;
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"avatars/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
        $currentsessionid = $_SESSION["userid"];
        $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET
avatar = ?, WHERE id = ?");
$insert = $query->execute(array(
      "$file_name","$currentsessionid"
));
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
} } ?>
```

Look at the SQL query carefully, I have table `users` and columns `id`, `avatar` ... avatar column is `varchar`, just i want to put filename to `avatar` where `current logged in user id`..

Comment: Your insert statement is wrong....

Comment: There is `where` in an `insert` an insert is adding a new record so it previously doesn't exist. Maybe you want an `update`?

Comment: It should be an update statement `update s set s.avatar = ? from users s where s.id = ?`.....

Comment: @chris85 No dude as you can see i am storing avatars in folder, I just want to add `$file_name` to `avatar` column where `currentsession id`

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes insert set is valid, but I doubt that is what he's looking for in this case.

Comment: @HalidKyazim Yea, so you need to **update** not **insert**.

Comment: Yea should be update.. but still i cant moake correct query:  `$currentsessionid = $_SESSION["userid"];
  $updateavatar = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users
SET avatar=?,
WHERE id=?");
$insert = $updateavatar->execute(array(
      "$file_name","$currentsessionid"`

Comment: What is `$insert` set as? Are the values set correctly? Variables don't need to be quoted. `$updateavatar->execute(array($file_name, $currentsessionid))`

Comment: Yes u are true but still the querry is uncorrect :   `$currentsessionid = $_SESSION["userid"];
  $updateavatar = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users
SET avatar=?,
WHERE id=?");
$updateavatar->execute(array(
      $file_name,$currentsessionid));`

Comment: `$insert` is true or false?

Comment: Just remove the extra comma `$conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET avatar=? WHERE id=?"); `

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your insert-statement.

An Insert have to look something like that:

```
INSERT INTO users (avatar, id) VALUES('avatar.png', $sessionid)
```

Comment: Then the best approach would be to use 
REPLACE INTO

Comment: Why?...can you elaborate?

Comment: I dont want to insert `id` i want to update `avatar` where `id`

Comment: I was confused from his first post that he wanted to insert

Answer (score 0):

There is no `session_start()` in the code you've shown us, nor is there anything to initialize your database connection. You've also not said what the problem *is*.

You should be checking the return values from `$conn->prepare()` and `$query->execute()`. If they are false, then you should be polling for errors then quoting them here if you can't solve the problem yourself.

> INSERT INTO users SET avatar = ?, WHERE id = ?

...is not SQL. You are confusing the syntax for INSERT with the syntax for UPDATE. jiGL has provided and example of how to to write an INSERT properly. Since you presumably already have a rescord in `users` representing the user, and want to change this to include the avatar path:

```
UPDATE users SET avatar = ? WHERE id = ?
```

BTW - the filename you are generating (kudos for [not using the name](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/local-file-inclusion-why-everything-you.html) supplied by the user) doesn't have an extension which makes it rather difficult to serve up again.

Comment: Ok i will explain you better 1- I have `session_start()` and `$_SESSION["userid"]` ... my code is : `$currentsessionid = $_SESSION["userid"];
  $updateavatar = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users
SET avatar=?,
WHERE id=?");
$insert = $updateavatar->execute(array(
      "$file_name","$currentsessionid"`